# C# project in sonarqube

Tags: c#, sonarqube

When I run sonar-runner for an analysis my simple C# project the analysis terminate on error on SonarLint.Runner.exe of permission denied:

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/opt/sonarqube-5.4/projects/ArturiCSharpSort/.sonar/SonarLint.Runner/SonarLint.Runner.exe": error=13, Permission denied
ERROR: Caused by: Cannot run program "/opt/sonarqube-5.4/projects/ArturiCSharpSort/.sonar/SonarLint.Runner/SonarLint.Runner.exe": error=13, Permission denied
ERROR: Caused by: error=13, Permission denied
```

Effectively

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 19456 Apr  5 11:14 .sonar/Lint.Runner/SonarLint.Runner.exe
```

This following is my sonar-project.properties:

```
# Root project information

sonar.projectKey=ArturiCSharpSort

sonar.projectName=ArturiCSharpSort

sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# Some properties that will be inherited by the modules

sonar.sources=.

#List of the module identifiers

#sonar.modules=

# Properties can obviously be overriden for

# each module - just prefix them with the module ID

#module1.sonar.projectName=

#module2.sonar.projectName=
```

I try to act a chmod on SonarLint.Runner.exe but it is rebuil at every analysis.
How can I run analysis on C# project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analysis of C# projects must be done on a Windows environment. Here it's failing because the project is analysed on Linux.

The thing is that SonarQube [C# Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/C%23+Plugin) really is targeted to the Windows .NET ecosystem, which is where you'd anyhow build/maintain .NET projects. It must be used with the [SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild), which requires MSBuild 14.0.

Comment: OK, thanks. After I try to build an Windows environment for SonarQube, and I wish it works.

Comment: Hi, now I'm running Visual Studio 2015 with SonarLint plugin. I connect to my server, bind it to SonarQube server, and I can run analysis. Wow!! But browsing webapp I can't find my application! What is the problem???