# Sonar Scanner for MSBuild on linux

Tags: c#, linux, msbuild, sonarqube

I'm looking for a way to run an analysis of a C# program on Linux. Searching I found that I can do this by Sonar Sanner for MSBuild, but I don't find a guide for do that on Linux.
Probably I miss something in sonar-project.properties or in configuration of sonarQube webapp in Administration->Scanner for MSBuild, Idon't know how to set in "Test project pattern" Key: sonar.cs.msbuild.testProjectPattern.

When I run my anysis I fond that I miss permissions to execute SonarLint.Runner.exe

Anybody can hel me?

Comment: This is your 3rd almost-identical question on this topic ([1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350843/problems-with-c-sharp-in-sonarqube-5-4), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36422599/c-sharp-project-in-sonarqube/36424098#36424098) , 3 here). Why insisting ? C# Plugin is targeted to the Windows .NET ecosystem, the Scanner for MSBuild [itself](https://github.com/SonarSource-VisualStudio/sonar-msbuild-runner) is a .NET project..

Comment: Thank n_stan And sorry for the third question. I was wandering why I can see fxcop rules and MSBbuild plugin from the webapp I can't run analysis. My headman say that it is imopossible, although I think it's plausible, Linux doesn't support MSBuild. Sorry again, Also for the replay I checked as correct. This question could also be deleted